# JS поделить большой ul список на несколько списков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток. *PHP* вытаскивает заполненный в админке один большой `ul` список. Задача написать скрипт так, чтобы этот большой список делило на несколько `ul` списков.

Никогда ничего подобного не выполнял, поэтому не очень понимаю, как это сделать на *JS*.

Примерно я сейчас вижу это так:

```
var li_sum = $("body ul li").length; //Находим кол-во элементов в списке
console.log("Кол-во элементов: " + liSum);

if (li_sum > 15) { //Если их больше 15, то разбиваем список на несколько списков и выводим.
    ...
    var ul = "<div class='col-md-4'><ul></ul></div>"
    $("body").append(ul);
    ...
}
```

Буду благодарен, любому совету или быть может, кто-то может подсказать в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: вы так хотите эмулировать разбивку на колонки что ли?

Comment: @teran да, задача весьма специфичная.

Comment: то есть `column-count` простой не вариант?

Comment: @teran дело в том, что в базе этой html разметки храниться вообще не будет. Человек в админке заполняет в редакторе обычный один большой ul список и сохраняет. PHP просто вытаскивает этот ul список из базы и вываливает его в один столбик. Моя задача этот список пошинковать и привести в нормальный колоночный вид.

Comment: @teran в принципе мне не так важны сами колонки, стили бустрап колонок я могу просто прописать в css на сам ul список. Мне важно именно разделить этот ul на равное кол-во ul в которых будет не больше 15-ти li строк.

Comment: хм... а что мешает сразу на стороне сервера на php это сделать?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин честно говоря, моё незнание и неопытность. Возможно, вы правы. Я так и думал сделать изначально, но столкнулся с вопросом, а как в php подсчитать кол-во li элементов в списке?

Я ведь вытаскиваю одним запросом -> 1 таблицу из базы с html списком. Поэтому метод с циклом тут не подойдет. Следовательно как мне получить кол-во li - не понятно.

Comment: @teran спасибо за подсказку, я понял, как использовать ваш вариант )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил:

Кол-во элементов li делю на 15, получаю число (сколько должно быть колонок) и подставляю это значение css свой-во **column-count:**.

Всё оказалось проще чем я думал. Спасибо за подсказку, **teran**.

Comment: да, про это и речь была.